# i am not able to receive my calls at my galaxy Y after updating the android 2.3.6

Tags: settings

i am not able to receive my calls at my galaxy Y after updating the android 2.3.6 although I can call in regular way.  whenever a person calls me he get phone busy notification, while i got a missed call notification with ringing any tone. I will be very thankfull if you help me in this concern.

Answer (score 0):

After reading alot of blogs I tried one thing and it worked. First of all I saved all of my contacts on SD card then I removed it and apply sttings ____privacy settings____"Factory Data Reset". After that I'm receiving my incoming calls in regular way even after inserting the SD card. I import all my contacts from sd card again. You ca also try this